# No Overload Method for 'Create'?

Tags: methods, overloading, revit

I have compiled the code, and have one problem with the 'Create' method. I cant figure it out...Any thoughts would be appreciated? This is for revit 2016.

```
public static void createSharedParam(Document doc, string name)
    {
        DefinitionFile defFile = doc.Application.OpenSharedParameterFile();
        DefinitionGroup dg = null;
        if (defFile == null) throw new Exception("No Shared Parameter File!");

        if (doc.ProjectInformation.Parameters.Cast<Parameter>().FirstOrDefault(q => q.Definition.Name.Equals(name)) != null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            string pgroup = "Parameter Group";
            dg = defFile.Groups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Name == pgroup);
            if (dg == null)
            {
                dg = defFile.Groups.Create(pgroup);
            }
        }
        Category myCategory = doc.Settings.Categories.get_Item(BuiltInCategory.OST_Views);
        CategorySet myCategories = doc.Application.Create.NewCategorySet();
        myCategories.Insert(myCategory);

        ElementBinding binding = doc.Application.Create.NewInstanceBinding(myCategories);

        Definition def = dg.Definitions.Cast<Definition>().FirstOrDefault(q => q.Name == name);

        if (def == null)
            def = dg.Definitions.Create(name, ParameterType.Text);

        bool result = doc.ParameterBindings.Insert(def, binding, BuiltInParameterGroup.PG_DATA);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard migration issue. Please check out the 'What's New' section for the Revit 2016 API. In your case, the relevant change probably occured in the Revit 2015 API: the introduction of an option class when creating a new shared parameter:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2015-api.html#2.04

**Shared parameter creation – description and user modifiability**

The new method:

- Definitions.Create(Autodesk.Revit.DB.ExternalDefinitonCreationOptions options);

creates a new shared parameter definition using an options class where any or all of the available options may be set (name and type are required, but GUID, user visible, user modifiable, and description are optional). This method replaces all other specific versions of Definitions.Create() which are now obsolete.

Here is a suitable sample code snippet:

https://github.com/jeremytammik/the_building_coder_samples/blob/master/BuildingCoder/BuildingCoder/CmdCreateSharedParams.cs#L201-L209

```
    //definition = group.Definitions.Create( defname, _deftype, visible ); // 2014

    ExternalDefinitionCreationOptions opt
      = new ExternalDefinitionCreationOptions(
        defname, _deftype );

    opt.Visible = visible;

    definition = group.Definitions.Create( opt ); // 2015
```

Comment: Thank you for the post.  I adjusted my code based on your post, and it compiles but i am now getting the following error?   'System.TypeLoadException'